# VBA Excel Extract Values Between Quotes and Put Into Array

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating an array like so:

```
Dim arTest(1 To 6) As Variant

arTest(1) = "0"
arTest(2) = "1"
arTest(3) = "2"
arTest(4) = "3"
arTest(5) = "4"
arTest(6) = "5"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="arTest", RefersTo:=arTest
```

The last line puts the array into a "named range" in an Excel sheet.

Later I want to create a new array in VBA from that named range. In Excel, the array is not stored in the value" field, but in the "refersto" field.

I can access it like so:

```
Dim nm As Name
Set nm = Names("arTest")
Debug.Print nm.RefersTo
```

That outputs this:

```
={"0","1","2","3","4","5"}
```

Now, I am not sure how I can get that string (I presume its a string?) into a VB array.

I am thinking it might be a regex type solution, but it would be nice if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps

```
   arOut = Evaluate(Names("arTest").Value)
```

Comment: Excellent and simple, many thanks. To help me and others, could you briefly explain how its working please?

Comment: Evaluate calculates a formula string the same way excel would in a cell

Comment: Hmm, I just realised, the array stored in my named range is actually in the format: ={0,1,2,3,4,5} (no quotes). This does not seem to behave and work the same way :/

Comment: Found my problem. My array is too long. As it is stored in the 'refersto' field, there is a 255 character limit, so my array string is being truncated :(

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example:

```
Dim s As String
Dim ss() As String ' or Variant, if you prefer
s = Replace(nm.Value, """", "")
ss = Split(Mid(s, 3, Len(s) - 3), ",")
```

Comment: @JosieP's answer is much better; it works for (non-string) numerical values as well.